# Этимология глагола таять

Tags: этимология

Подскажите, пожалуйста, откуда происходит этот глагол. Что значит *тает снег*? Тает - значит уходит в тайну?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Происхождение многих слов Вы можете узнать с помощью этимологических словарей. Снег тает — значит плавится, становится жидким.

> ТАЯТЬ
>
> > Общеслав. Суф. производное от того же корня, что греч. tēkō «плавлю», лат. tabēre «растоплять, плавить», др.-в.-нем. dewen «таять», др.-инд. tōyam «вода». Таять буквально — «превращаться в воду». *Школьный этимологический словарь русского языка. Происхождение слов. — М.: Дрофа Н. М. Шанский, Т. А. Боброва 2004*
> >
> > Общеславянское – tajati (чахнуть). Древнерусское и старославянское – таяти (истекать, чахнуть). В русском языке известно употребление слова с XI в. в форме «таяти» и в значении «чахнуть», «истекать». Одновременно с этим форма «растаяти» – «обессилеть», «опечалиться». С XV в. слово употребляется в значении «растаять». Производные слова появились значительно позже.
> >     *Этимологический словарь русского языка. М.: Русский язык от А до Я. Издательство <ЮНВЕС> Москва 2003*
> >
> > таю I та́ю I, та́ять, укр. та́яти, др.-русск. таяти, таю, сербск.-цслав. таетъ τήκεται, болг. та́я, сербохорв. та̏jати, та̏jē, словен. tájati, tа̑jе, чеш. táti, taji, польск. tajać, taję, в.-луж. tać, н.-луж. tajaś. Сюда же чеш. taviti "растоплять, плавить", слвц. tаvit᾽. Родственно греч. τήκω "плавлю, истребляю", дор. τά̄κω – то же, τακερός "растопленный", осет. tΏаjun "таять" (Хюбшман, Osset. Еt. 58), лат. tābēs ж. "растопление, растворение, тление", tābum ср. р. "гниющая жидкость", tābeō, -ērе "плавить", арм. tΏаnаm "увлажняю, мочу", д.-в.-н. douwen, dеwеn "таять", др.-ирл. tām "смерть, мор", кимр. toddi "liquēscere", а также др.-инд. tṓуаm ср. р. "вода". *Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973*

Answer (score 0):

Таять — превращаться в жидкое состояние под действием тепла, влаги; уменьшаться, растопляясь, сограя (о свече); становиться незаметным, постепенно исчезать; уменьшаться в объеме, числе и т. п.; *разг.* приходить в умиленное, разнеженное состояние, млеть.

Это древнее слово считается частью индоевропейского фонда, имеет соответствие во многих индоевропейских языках (польское *tajać* или, например, латинское *tabere* "делаться влажным, плавить"). Таким образом, можно говорить, что это **исконно славянское слово**. В русском языке известно примерно с XI века.

Указания на связь со словом *тайна* вызывают сомнения (см. словарь Фасмера).

*В ответе используются данные "Этимологического словаря русского языка" М. Фасмера, "Этимологического словаря современного русского языка" А. К. Шапошникова и "Этимологического словаря русского языка" М. Э. Рут.*

Comment: Спасибо за коменты.Я вот покопался в нети и подумал,что возможно корень ТАЙ общий у многих слов,например Алтай,Китай,тайна,тайга.
И вот тай где то описано было,что означает предел,вершину,конец,даль.И вроде бы сростается такая версия,что Алтай это золотая гора,вершина.,Китай не знаю,что)),тайна значит даль и предел не видимый.,тайга это типа тайная тропа неизведанная,,и таять значит кончаться или уходить в тайну за предел видения.
Как вам такая версия?))

Comment: @DmitryPetrov есть предположение, но малоубедительное, что слова *Алтай* и *тайга* действительно этимологически связаны (общим тюркским корнем) (см. словарь Фасмера). *Китай* и *тайна* совершенно не родственны; *Китай* — слово из китайского языка (из одного его диалекта), *тайна*, как минимум, имеет индоевропейское происхождение. Все приведенные вами объяснения нельзя считать научными.